# Symfony: Embeding Collection of Forms issue

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

Symfony version: 3

I need to create a form that insert user data into two tables. So I am following [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) method in the Symfony doc.
I have two entities called **Users** and **Address** and I have created two form builders like below,

**AddressType**

```
class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('address');
        $builder->add('postCode');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'PIE10Bundle\Entity\Address',
        ));
    }
 }
```

**UserType**

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('firstname');
        $builder->add('lastname');

        $builder->add('address', 
                      CollectionType::class, 
                      array(
                            'entry_type' => AddressType::class
         ));

        $builder->add('Add User', SubmitType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'PIE10Bundle\Entity\Users',

        ));
    }
}
```

and my Contoller,

```
public function addNewUserAction(Request $request)
{
    $user    = new Users;
    $address = new Address;

    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    return $this->render('PIE10Bundle:Form:newuser.html.twig',
                         array(
                                'title' => 'Add New User',
                                'form'  => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

and yes finally the view `PIE10Bundle:Form:newuser.html.twig`

```
{% extends "PIE10Bundle::layout.html.twig" %}
{% block cmi_body %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {{form_start(form)}}
            {{form_widget(form)}}
        {{form_end(form)}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    {{ dump(form) }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And I am getting something like the below. 
[image]

in the form I am not getting the text fields for following

```
$builder->add('address');
$builder->add('postCode');
```

I need to know if I am missing something in my code or the reason for not getting the two text fields and how to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a 1 to 1 relationship between user and address? You might want to show your mapping.  How you have your relationship set up between those two entities would determine which form field type to use.

Comment: yes this is 1 to 1 relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your User class:

change:

```
$builder->add('address', 
     CollectionType::class, 
     array(
           'entry_type' => AddressType::class,array('label' => false)
     ));
```

to:

```
$builder->add('address', AddressType::class);
```

CollectionType is used when your relationship is one-to-many or many-to-many. So if your user was able to have multiple addresses, you would use CollectionType (but with some modification to your code).

**UPDATE to deal with multiple labels:**
You have two Address labels because when you add the formtype AddressType in your UserForm it takes on the label "Address" by default. Also inside your AddressType you have a field for "Address" which takes on the label "Address" by default, hence the two labels. Look at the code above. I've added `array('label' => false)` to the AddressType which will remove the first instance and leave the label on the actual field.

Comment: I think he wants to see AddressType form fields in the view. Your way able to save only one address data.

Comment: See his comments. It is a 1 to 1 relationship, so he shouldn't be using CollectionType.  Using the custom form type will get it into the view because he's rendering the entire form.  When using CollectionType you have to set up 'allow_add', 'allow_delete' in order to add/remove items from the collection.

Comment: You you right about CollectionType, but he wants to see other Type fields in the same form. He should extend the AddressType from UserType.

Comment: You don't need to extend anything.  the address entity has it's own form type.  User has it's own form type.  If the mapping is set up correctly, you add the address form to the user form with formbuilder as I've shown.  The way he's rendering the form will render all the fields.

Comment: Yes :)) this works for me but I am getting extra "Address" in the form and you can [see it here](https://postimg.org/image/9yhvhlmpp/). the HTML for this extra address is like this `<label class="required">Address</label>` and are there any way to get rid of this extra label

Comment: Yes the extra label removed for `array('label' => false)` and thanks :))

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend AddressType from UserType

Change your **AddressType** like that;

```
    class AddressType extends UserType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array         $options)
        {
            parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
            $builder->add('address');
            $builder->add('postCode');
        }

        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'PIE10Bundle\Entity\Address',
            ));
        }
     }
```

delete this part;

```
     $builder->add('address', 
                  CollectionType::class, 
                  array(
                        'entry_type' => AddressType::class
     ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the __construct of your user, add a new address instance

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->address = new Address();
}
```

With that you will see the missing form fields

Comment: Did you mean in the `Users Entity` (which is the entity) or `UserType` (which is the FormType for Users Entity)